# what is the way to replace a line in a file using python

Tags: python, file, io

I want to replace a line in a text file using Python. Basically I am looping over a file and when I find a relevant line that needs to be replaced, I want to replace it at the same position in the file.

Can this be done in Python without creating a completely new file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using the [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) for this. It has an option for making a backup file, and it preserves permissions.

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input([filename], inplace=True):
    if condition:
        sys.stdout.write(newline)
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

This *does* create a new (temporary) file, then renames that file to `filename`, so the change appears to be in-place.

Comment: It gives me this error 
  sys.write(finallog)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: Sorry, `sys.write` should have been `sys.stdout.write`.